# converting string to array of bytes

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I wanted to convert `string` into `array` of `bytes`. How can i do that ?

Actually i wanted to read from the file and convert all that data into `array` of `bytes` .

If converted how can i obtain the size of that `array` ?

After obtaining array of bytes i wanted to get the pointer of type `LPVOID` and make it point to that array of bytes , to use the function `BOOL WritePrinter(
  __in   HANDLE hPrinter,
  __in   LPVOID pBuf,
  __in   DWORD cbBuf,
  __out  LPDWORD pcWritten
);`

The second argument demands pointer towards array of bytes . But i don't know any method that does this.

Comment: You want to change "Hello world" string to array of bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a `string` to a `char*` using

```
char* bytes = str.c_str();
```

The length can be obtained through

```
int len = str.length();
```

The pointer can simply be casted to `LPVOID`

```
LPVOID ptr = (LPVOID) bytes;
```

Comment: `c_str()` returns a `const char *`, casting away constness probably wouldnt cause any problems as long as you're sure the string data is modifiable, but I dont like doing it...just in case.

Comment: You wont get something other than `const char*` out of the string, and copying it over seems to be overkill.

Comment: what about `&myString[0]` ? - im not 100% sure if the memory is always contiguous come to think of it. do you know?

Comment: @Node: Every popular implementation now has contiguous storage for `std::string`, and the C++0x standard will guarantee it.

Comment: What about using the string::data() method?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the data in the `std::string` by calling the [`std::string::data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) member function, that will return a `const char*`, alternatively you can just use [`std::string::operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) to manipulate the `std::string` as if it were a char array.

If you want it as a vector, you can create one with:

```
std::vector<char> myVector(myString.beging(), myString.end());
char *myCharPtr = &myVector.front();
```

**Edit:** This is probably the quickest/easier way...

```
std::string myStr = "testing";
char *myCharPtr = &myStr[0];
```